# how to add begin of line with multilines with delimiter?

Tags: bash

I have a file like this:

Input:

```
---
a
b
c
d
---
a
b
c
d
---
a
b
c
d
```

And I would like to add same structure at each block delimited by --- like:

Output:

```
---
1: a
2: b
3: c
4: d
---
1: a
2: b
3: c
4: d
---
1: a
2: b
3: c
4: d
```

I try using sed like:

```
sed -i '1s/a: /\1/'
```

and so on but it keeps adding to the first line.

Best regards.

Comment: What is the end goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying the store variable from json file with jq command. I am using it in a loop and I store all results in a file. each result is separated by ---. and after i would like to put title to the variable.

Comment: Please, don't throw away the formatting help from other users.

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Thank you for the link @Cyrus
I am sorry choroba

Comment: The second part of your question is not very clear and confuses the topic. The first part is quite straightforward. You have given an example input and the required output. This can be handled in a number of simple ways, sed being just one way to do it. However, the second part of the question introduces JSON, which was not mentioned anywhere in the first section.

Perhaps you could limit your question to just the first part.

Or.. better still.. describe the entire problem you are trying to solve, with the original source of input data, and the desired final result.

Comment: I don't understand how you get from `a` `b` `c` `d` to `name x`, `status x`, `disk x`; I can't tell if you're trying to describe two different issues/problems, or if you've changed your data set halfway through the question ... ?????

Comment: You mention that `sed -i '1s/a: /\1/' ` *keeps adding to the first line* but on my system this `sed` script generates an error; please update the question with the `sed` command you're using that *keeps adding to the first line*

Comment: I edited to make it simple, I have the input and output I would like to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '{ pfx=++count ": "        # set default prefix as incremented counter + ": "
       if ($0 ~ /^---/)        # if lines starts with "---" then ...
           pfx=count=""        # reset variables
       print pfx $0            # print prefix plus current line
     }' x
```

or as a one-liner (sans comments):

```
awk '{ pfx=++count ": "; if ($0 ~ /^---/) pfx=count=""; print pfx $0 }' x
```

This generates:

```
---
1: a
2: b
3: c
4: d
---
1: a
2: b
3: c
4: d
---
1: a
2: b
3: c
4: d
```